# change rect position in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to change where the ship from Alien Invasion is drawn when the game starts and I don't actually know where to make the changes.
I want it to be at a selected position by me when the game starts, not midbottom.
Ship code:

```
class Ship(Sprite):
"""A class to manage the ship."""

def __init__(self,ai_game):
    """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.settings = ai_game.settings
    self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

    #Load the ship image and get its rect.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
    self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    #Store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position.
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    #Movement flags
    self.moving_right = False
    self.moving_left = False
    self.moving_up = False
    self.moving_down = False

def update(self):
    """Update the ship's position based on the movement flags."""
    #Update the ship's x value, not the rect.
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
        self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom <= self.screen_rect.bottom:
        self.y += self.settings.ship_speed


    #Update rect object from self.x.
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y
        

def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

def center_ship(self):
    """Center the ship on the screen."""
    self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the position of the ship in the `rect` attribute. You can do this when you get the bounding rectangle from the image:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.x = 200
self.rect.y = 100
```

Or even shorter using the keyword attributes of the method [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (200, 100))
```

I suggest to add `x` and `y` attributes to the constructor of the `Ship` class:

```py
class Ship(Sprite):
"""A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game, x, y):
        # [...]

        #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

        # [...]
```